# Prepare WHERE Clause string for given values

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following details to prepare string as shown below in the expected result.

Given:

```
DECLARE @VValue VARCHAR(MAX) = 'John Dee|Mak Don'
DECLARE @VColumns VARCHAR(MAX) = 'FName|LName'
DECLARE @VCondition VARCHAR(500) = 'OR'
DECLARE @VPattern VARCHAR(MAX) = 'Start|Exact'
DECLARE @VCheck VARCHAR(MAX) = '1|0'
DECLARE @String VARCHAR(MAX) = ''
```

Expected result:

```
(
    ISNULL(PATINDEX(''John%'', FName), ''0'') > 0 AND 
    ISNULL(PATINDEX(''Dee%'', FName), ''0'') > 0
)  
OR 
(
    ISNULL(PATINDEX(''Mak'', LName), ''0'') +  
    ISNULL(PATINDEX(''Don'', LName), ''0'') > 0 
)
```

My attempt:

```
SET @VCondition = '|'+@VCondition;

 SET @String = REPLACE('('+REPLACE(STUFF((SELECT N')  '+DS3.Item+' (' + NCHAR(10) + 
             STUFF((SELECT 
                         CASE WHEN DS4.Item = 'Start' AND DS5.Item = 0
                               THEN
                                    N' + ' +NCHAR(10)+
                                    N'ISNULL(PATINDEX('''''+DSn.Item +'%'''''+ N',' + DSc.Item  + N'),''''0'''')'
                                WHEN DS4.Item = 'Start' AND DS5.Item = 1
                                THEN
                                    N' > 0 AND ' +NCHAR(10)+
                                    N'ISNULL(PATINDEX('''''+DSn.Item +'%'''''+ N',' + DSc.Item  + N'),''''0'''')'
                          ELSE
                                ''
                          END 
                          +
                          CASE WHEN DS4.Item = 'Exact' AND DS5.Item = 0
                               THEN
                                   N' + ' +NCHAR(10)+
                                   N'ISNULL(PATINDEX('''''+DSn.Item +''''''+ N',' + DSc.Item  + N'),''''0'''')'
                               WHEN DS4.Item = 'Exact' AND DS5.Item = 1
                               THEN
                                   N' > 0 AND ' +NCHAR(10)+
                                   N'ISNULL(PATINDEX('''''+DSn.Item +''''''+ N',' + DSc.Item  + N'),''''0'''')'
                          ELSE '' 
                          END
                    FROM dbo.f_split(DS1.Item,' ') DSn
                         CROSS APPLY dbo.f_split(DS2.Item,',') DSc
                    ORDER BY DSc.id, DSn.id
                    FOR XML PATH(N'')),1,4,N'')
            FROM dbo.udf_split (@VValue,'|') DS1
            CROSS APPLY dbo.udf_split (@VColumns,'|') DS2
            CROSS APPLY dbo.udf_split (@VCondition,'|') DS3
            CROSS APPLY dbo.udf_split (@VPattern,'|') DS4
            CROSS APPLY dbo.udf_split (@VCheck, '|') DS5
            WHERE DS1.id = DS2.id AND DS2.ID = DS3.ID AND DS3.ID = DS4.ID AND DS4.ID = DS5.ID
            ORDER BY DS1.id
            FOR XML PATH(N'')),1,9,N''),'&gt;','>') + N') )','&amp;gt;','>');

PRINT(@String);
```

But I'm getting the following result:

```
( AND 
    ISNULL(PATINDEX(''John%'', FName), ''0'') > 0 AND 
    ISNULL(PATINDEX(''Dee%'', FName), ''0''))  OR (
    ISNULL(PATINDEX(''Mak'', LName), ''0'') + 
    ISNULL(PATINDEX(''Don'', LName), ''0'')) )
```

Comment: It seems to me like you are putting way too much of this logic in the database. This would be handled much easier using any programming language than in any version of SQL.

Comment: also i hope dbo.f_split is a good splitter cause it's easy to have them perform terribly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many attempt, following does the job done.

Query:

```
DECLARE @VValue VARCHAR(MAX) = 'John Dee|Mak Don'
DECLARE @VColumns VARCHAR(MAX) = 'FName|LName'
DECLARE @VCondition VARCHAR(500) = 'OR'
DECLARE @VPattern VARCHAR(MAX) = 'Start|Exact'
DECLARE @VCheck VARCHAR(MAX) = '1|0'
DECLARE @String VARCHAR(MAX) = ''

SET @VCondition = '|'+@VCondition;

 SET @String = REPLACE('('+STUFF((SELECT N' > 0 )  '+DS3.Item+' (' + NCHAR(10) + 
             REPLACE(STUFF((SELECT 
                         CASE WHEN DS4.Item = 'Start' AND DS5.Item = 0
                               THEN
                                    N'    +     ' +NCHAR(10)+
                                    N'ISNULL(PATINDEX('''''+DSn.Item +'%'''''+ N',' + DSc.Item  + N'),''''0'''')'
                                WHEN DS4.Item = 'Start' AND DS5.Item = 1
                                THEN
                                    N' > 0 AND ' +NCHAR(10)+
                                    N'ISNULL(PATINDEX('''''+DSn.Item +'%'''''+ N',' + DSc.Item  + N'),''''0'''')'
                          ELSE
                                ''
                          END 
                          +
                          CASE WHEN DS4.Item = 'Exact' AND DS5.Item = 0
                               THEN
                                   N'    +     ' +NCHAR(10)+
                                   N'ISNULL(PATINDEX('''''+DSn.Item +''''''+ N',' + DSc.Item  + N'),''''0'''')'
                               WHEN DS4.Item = 'Exact' AND DS5.Item = 1
                               THEN
                                   N' > 0 AND ' +NCHAR(10)+
                                   N'ISNULL(PATINDEX('''''+DSn.Item +''''''+ N',' + DSc.Item  + N'),''''0'''')'
                          ELSE '' 
                          END
                    FROM dbo.f_split(DS1.Item,' ') DSn
                         CROSS APPLY dbo.f_split(DS2.Item,',') DSc
                    ORDER BY DSc.id, DSn.id
                    FOR XML PATH(N'')),1,11,N''),'&gt;','>')
            FROM dbo.udf_split (@VValue,'|') DS1
            CROSS APPLY dbo.udf_split (@VColumns,'|') DS2
            CROSS APPLY dbo.udf_split (@VCondition,'|') DS3
            CROSS APPLY dbo.udf_split (@VPattern,'|') DS4
            CROSS APPLY dbo.udf_split (@VCheck, '|') DS5
            WHERE DS1.id = DS2.id AND DS2.ID = DS3.ID AND DS3.ID = DS4.ID AND DS4.ID = DS5.ID
            ORDER BY DS1.id
            FOR XML PATH(N'')),1,13,N''),'&gt;','>') + N' > 0 ) ';

PRINT(@String);
```

Output:

```
( 
    ISNULL(PATINDEX(''John%'',FName),''0'') > 0 AND 
    ISNULL(PATINDEX(''Dee%'',FName),''0'') > 0 
)  
OR 
(
    ISNULL(PATINDEX(''Mak'',LName),''0'')    +     
    ISNULL(PATINDEX(''Don'',LName),''0'') > 0 
)
```